# Ajax query failed with status 0 in phone gap iOS app

Tags: jquery, ios, ajax, cordova

I am developing an ios app with phonegap in which I am listing all the near by venues by using foursquare api.This is the code I have used for listing the venues.

```
$.getJSON('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll='+pos+'&radius=10000&client_id=2POUFAUU4ZBJ2MTDOY3S2YHR2NIT52FYW0LUTPHBMNTJFJNQ&client_secret=YFDZI1YWV3ZI5S5SPM2DZJEQIEBPIDJ5XFZBWTIKIQZVQNYM&v=20120101&limit=60',
          function(data) {

          console.log(pos);
          $.each(data.response.venues, function(i,venues){

                 content = '<li id="list-item"> <p><a href="#reviewPage" onClick=" return reviewPageAction(this)">' + venues.name + '</li>';

                 $(content).appendTo("#mer");

                 });
          });
```

As you can c I have given a link for each list items,which will load a review page,which will displays the details of the venue. I have given an onClick function for each list item which will fetch some details from my database using ajax call to my php file.

The following is the code for onclick function

```
$.ajax({
               type: 'GET',

               url: 'http://127.0.0.1/myPHPFile.php',
               data: { id: venueId},
               success: function(response) {


                   alert(response);
               },
               error:function(xhr,status,error){

                alert("failure "+xhr.status);
                $("#result").html('there is error while submit');
                }
               });
```

For testing purpose ,in myPHPFile.php am just echoing a string only.

The problem is  I am always getting an error with status 0. But it is not showing any error in simulator. In device and desktop browser its showing error!! Please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

Are you configured access in config.xml? Like:

```
<access origin="https://api.foursquare.com" />
```

or for all domains:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

More info at: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/guide_project-settings_index.md.html

Comment: But the foursquare things are working fine.The only problem is ajax request to my own php file is not working properly. I am geting status 0 error

Comment: If your PHP is under a domain like http://myserver/myphp.php, and your app is running on file:// under PhonegapApp or Browser, is an invalid cross-domain access. You should configure accesible domains under config.xml or add <access origin="*" /> in config.xml

Comment: I have checked config.xml and <access origin="*"> is already present in that file.

Comment: Can u please tell me how to configure it manually to provide access to my php file

Comment: Look this: http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com.es/2011/12/on-third-day-of-phonegapping-getting.html

Comment: Look this too: http://debug.phonegap.com/ It could be useful to debug your phonegapApp remotely under Chrome Browser.

Comment: I have tried what they mentioned in simonmacdonald.blogpost. But while alerting the resposne string am getting a null string.

Comment: The problem is the IP, look at my answer

Answer (score 1):

`http://127.0.0.1/` it's the same machine, so if you try it on the simulator, it works because you have the PHP script on that machine.
If you try it on the device, `http://127.0.0.1/` is the device, the device doesn't have the PHP script.

You have to use the local IP of the server, something like this but changing 192.168.1.20 to the real local IP of the server (you can know it with `ipconfig` on windows, or `ifconfig` on mac/linux)

```
$.ajax({
               type: 'GET',

               url: 'http://192.168.1.20/myPHPFile.php',
               data: { id: venueId},
               success: function(response) {


                   alert(response);
               },
               error:function(xhr,status,error){

                alert("failure "+xhr.status);
                $("#result").html('there is error while submit');
                }
               });
```

Answer (score -1):

Use JSONP, return data in PHP:

```
echo $_GET['callback']. '('. json_encode($returnData). ');';
```

jQuery:

```
$.getJSON('yourApiUrl',
 function(data) {
  console.log(data);
 });
```